# How is the stub dollar function accessed after jQuery is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a little confused on [how this works](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/17/stop-paying-your-jquery-tax) insofar as I am seeing circular logic:

1. Define a stub dollar function:

   ```
   window.q=[];
   window.$=function(f){
     q.push(f);
   };
   ```
2. Right after jQuery loads, add any functions pushed onto the stub to jquery on load dollar function:

   ```
   $.each(q,function(index,f){
     $(f)
   });
   ```

How is it that these two dollar functions are properly accessed?  After jQuery loads, hasn't it already taken over the dollar function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stub `$` function pushes each function it receives onto the array `q`.

When jQuery loads, it replaces your `$` with its own, but it does *not* overwrite your `q` array.

The final code uses jQuery's `$.each()` method to iterate over your `q` array, calling jQuery's `$` function on each of your functions (`f` in the loop). So it's as if you'd called `$(f)` using jQuery's `$` in the first place. When used like this, `$` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of delayed registration of [onready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) methods.

How is it working

1. We register a stub `$` method which dumps all the onready methods to a global array
2. Once jquery is loaded `$` is replaced with jQuery object, but the global array `q` still has all the onready methods passed to jquery, prior to its load
3. when [jQuery onready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is fired, we iterate through the global array `q` and call each of the registered functions.

Answer (score 1):

> After jQuery loads, hasn't it already taken over the dollar function?

That's the whole idea; the temporary function that create in the `<head>` creates a stub for jQuery that only implements `jQuery(fn)`; any code that uses `$(function() { ... })` between this definition and when jQuery is loaded will be kept in `window.q`.

Once jQuery has been loaded, the `$` is replaced but the kept list of callback functions is still available and will be handled in a batch operation.